# What do I have to get to cut the small ceramic tile for a back splash?

Tags: tile, cutting

What do I have to get to cut small ceramic tile for a kitchen back splash ?

Comment: What kind of tile is it exactly?  What kind of cuts do you need to make?

Comment: @DMoore you gave an answer a while back that, along with others, gives the OP all the choices. http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/32364/how-to-i-cut-glass-and-marble-tiles-when-they-are-on-a-mesh-backing?rq=1 . Albeit ceramic rather than marble and glass, it takes the same choice of tools, each with their own pros and cons. It will boil down to a matter of money, the best choices are not cheap, renting a wet saw, IMHO.